# Accessing my IG media without having to setup business accounts and await reviews

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to access my media data from IG using the facebook graph api and everything seems to be working but I have gotten to a point where i need to access data requiring instagram_basic permissions but this requires a review on the app and given I've dealt with facebook a lot I imagine this could take a really long time.

I want to simply access the images and some other data to show on a website. I am aware I can use the instagram api directly for personal accounts but this is somewhat limited and it's my understand that this will become deprecated at some point soon. Is there any specific way to do this? I can get access to my IG account through the API but can't actually access any of the media objects.

I appreciate any help you guys can provide

I've hit a road block and all the documentation points to getting it reviewed. This at the moment is just a test app to see if it works so it seems a completely pointless endeavour to go through the full process.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your actual question, but yes, the available IG permissions require review and business verification and there is no other way to get them approved w/o going through review.